# No visual effects in Media Center in Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-media-center

I tried to use Remote Desktop to connect from my laptop to my other computer (both running Windows 7 Ultimate). I then started Media Center, which worked ok. But there were no transition effects? Is it possible to enable the effects again? Couldn't find the options for it in the media center settings that are usually there... The menu transitions isn't very important, but I would like to have the transitions in the photo slide shows at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote desktop is considered a very low bandwidth connection and most built in Windows software handles this by scaling back on effects to improve performance. Remote desktop isn't really made for handling slideshows/movies/large images.

You also won't be able to use and directx or 3d apps since they won't see it as you having a 3d capable gfx card.